# Join Query on Mysql, for social network

Tags: mysql, performance

Please help me, how to  faster for join table, my query

```sql
SELECT tab1.idxx, tab1.una, tab1.isi, tab1.berkat, tab1.type, tab1.forr, tab1.ft, tab1.llt 
  FROM akpen t2 , tab1
 WHERE una = t2.tuj
   AND t2.perm =  'adhy' 
 order by time DESC 
 limit 7
```

My site has 10,000 users and the query takes 1 minute to load the data, such as images often appear error

https://i.stack.imgur.com/QjgzD.jpg

in my query, I restrict the data to only 7 in the show, but when I "Explain" my query, mysql to read all the data and then in the limit, not the limit of data prior

Comment: image loading error is out of MySQL query speed scope.

Comment: The query to be wrong because the data read speed is very slow,

Comment: $select = mysql_query("SELECT status.id, status.username, status.status, status.says, status.tipe, status.tujuan, status.firsttime, status.lasttime FROM aktifitas_pengikut t2 INNER JOIN status ON status.username =t2.diikuti WHERE t2.permintaan = 'adhymusaad' and status.privacy='' order by date DESC limit 7");

while($test= @mysql_fetch_array($select)) { }

Answer (score 0):

1 minute for 10000 users is too much.

Please add indexes to fields, which is in JOIN construction.
And try so:

```
 SELECT tab1.idxx, tab1.una, tab1.isi, tab1.berkat, tab1.type, tab1.forr, tab1.ft, tab1.llt 
  FROM akpen t2
 INNER JOIN tab1 ON tab1.una = t2.tuj 
 WHERE t2.perm =  'adhy' 
 order by time DESC 
 limit 7
```

Comment: Remove comma after 'from akpen t2'. Other than adding index, how this query hasten the process of execution? 'FROM akpen t2 , tab1' also doing inner join by default, right?

Comment: Thanks, comma was removed. i think - indexes speed executing query very well.

Comment: Still the same error appeared,user first I was a little, query it runs perfectly, but now I've reached 10,000 users, the error like picture

Comment: Still the same error appeared,user first I was a little, query it runs perfectly, but now I've reached 10,000 users, the error like picture

Comment: Please give your PHP code like
$query = mysql_query($query);
while ($row = mysel_fetch_assoc($query))

Comment: My query:

$select = mysql_query("SELECT status.id, status.username, status.status, status.says, status.tipe, status.tujuan, status.firsttime, status.lasttime 
FROM aktifitas_pengikut t2  INNER JOIN status ON status.username =t2.diikuti
WHERE t2.permintaan =  'adhymusaad' and status.privacy='' order by date DESC limit 7");

Comment: while($test= @mysql_fetch_array($select))
{
}